# How to stringify circular JSON object and save it to file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js, stringify

I'm working on a radial tree diagram in javascript using d3.js and jquery. I use json files to load data into a javascript var. After working on a diagram and making some changes, e.g. changing parent of some nodes, I want to stringify data and save as a json file. When I stringify treeData variable, which includes all json data, and wanted to display it, I receive only the root node stringified. This is my code:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(treeData.children, function(key,value){
    if(key == "children"){
        return undefined;
    }
    return value;
});
alert("Json: " + json);
```

Also I don't know why the key is set to "children".
My JSON file structure:

```
{
 "name": "root",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "child1",
   "children": [ ... ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: You are specifically excluding the `children` properties when serialising the object, how do you expect the result being anything but just the root node without the `children` property?

Comment: You're right. The structure of the object in js var is not the same as the json file I loaded. I just change "children" to "parent" and it's working properly. It came out to me a moment earlier I read your answer but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that using tree data will return with a loop and circular data error. Switching key from "children" to "parent" give a json without references to the parents and work properly.

Answer (score 3):

You have a `children` key in your object literal so it is passed to the callBack and then for some reason you are returning undefined, which will remove that key from the result.

Answer (score 2):

Circular JSON Objects can be stringified and saved with the following approach:

```
import stringify from 'json-stringify-safe';
import fs from 'fs';

const content = stringify(myCircularJSONObject);

fs.writeFile('./data.json', content, ()=>{console.log('CREATED')});
```

Comment: Lonely, usually it's best etiquette to add text along with code samples - explain what it is you're trying to suggest as a solution.  What is different about your code from what the original question had?  What approach are you suggesting?  Things like that will help you have a better answer that is more likely to be accepted by others.

Comment: You're right, I've updated my answer. The accepted answer provides no solution, but there is one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to achieve stringifying of an object structured as:

```
var obj = {};
obj.circle = obj;
var str = JSON.stringify(obj);
// → Error
```

This object will return an error with JSON.stringify although is otherwise valid.
If you don't mind the readability of the stringified object, I suggest using [CircularJSON](https://github.com/WebReflection/circular-json#circularjson):

Install when using Node.js:

```
npm install --save circular-json
```

Install for web:

```
<script src="build/circular-json.js"></script>
```

And usage:

```
var object = {};
object.arr = [
    object, object
];
object.arr.push(object.arr);
object.obj = object;

var serialized = CircularJSON.stringify(object);
// → '{"arr":["~","~","~arr"],"obj":"~"}'

var unserialized = CircularJSON.parse(serialized);
// → { arr: [ [Circular], [Circular] ], obj: [Circular] }
```